# Facing issue with selenium when I try to use "By.CSS_SELECTOR"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to build a script, that can click on the Facebook group category "join" button, when certain conditions are met.

The script is already able to navigate "https://www.facebook.com/search/groups/?q=nature_lover" path using selenium.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QJhy.png

After navigating to that path I used this code to handle, each group component data.

```
all_group_elements = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[role=article]")

for group_element in group_elements:
   
   group_name = str(element.text.split('\n')[0])
   group_button = str(element.text.split('\n')[-1])

   if group_button=="Join":
       group_button_target = f"Join Group {group_name}"
   if group_button=="Follow Group":
       group_button_target = f"Follow Group {group_name}"

   # I used this code to target and click the "join" button. 
   self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f"div[aria-label={group_button_target}]").click()
```

I'm also using "WebDriverWait" in the script. What is the issue here?

Comment: what is the error ?  where is the rest of the code ?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The code is bit long to put here, I have edited the question as simple as possible

Comment: only the minimum reproducable example is required. Not the whole code !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with `f"div[aria-label={group_button_target}]"`

That translates to something like `"div[aria-label=Join Group NAME]"`

That's a problem, because the value of the attribute contains spaces and **you need quotes around the value if there are spaces**.

Eg:

Bad: `'TAG[ATTRIBUTE=SOME VALUE]'`

Good: `'TAG[ATTRIBUTE="SOME VALUE"]'`

Those quotes are important if the value contains spaces. You may want to change that line to:

```py
self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'div[aria-label="{group_button_target}"]').click()
```

Comment: What is the best way to target that "join" button, because for f'div[aria-label="{group_button_target} can have duplicates right? I mean 2 groups can have the same name. so could you tell me what is the best solution for this?

Comment: By default, if there's more than one matching selector, than the first one will be chosen. If you want to create a list of all matching elements, you can use: ``self.driver.find_elements(by=by, value=selector)``. Then you can iterate through list items and perform actions.